# How do I match substrings not containing a specific substring

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a substring which does not contain a specific substring `"href"`

**THE STRING**

```
blabla bladibla <a class="link-ch" href="add-tt-2021-s18-chapter-4.1.html#ch-9-1-1-21-3">9.1.1.21.3</a> blabla <a class="link-ch" href="add-tt-2021-s18-chapter-4.1.html#ch-9-1-1-21-5">9.1.1.21.5</a> more blabla <a class="link-tbl">tabel 9.1.1.21.6</a>, some more bladibla
```

**THE DESIRED OUTCOME:**
The following line should be matched:

```
<a class="link-tbl">tabel 9.1.1.21.6</a>
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**
I tried a negative lookahead, but this still matches a-tags having `href` as a substring

```
<a class="link.*?(?!href).*?<\/a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
<a (?![^<>]*href)[^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuMOq0/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `<a` : Match `<a`
- `(?![^<>]*href)`: Negative lookahead that makes sure that there is no `href` ahead after 0 or more of any char that are not `<` and `>`
- `[^>]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that are not `>`
- `>`: Match `>`
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `<\/a>`: Match `</a>`

Comment: great explanation using Lookahead & Lookbehind with in regex. wow great...

Comment: @anubhava Not related to this question, but in general. I see that you have authored a book for regex on Java. I do not use Java at all. I would like to understand regex, however. Is your book helpful in that regard or is it too Java specific?

Comment: @Tryer: My book has lot of in-depth info on regex but it is mostly Java centric. If you are not into Java I suggest you refer this great online tutorial: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html